# Does Scheffe always show wider confidence bands than Bonferroni?

Tags: confidence-interval, bonferroni

Bonferroni simultaneous confidence intervals are built for finite parameters, while Scheffe simultaneous confidence intervals are built for infinite parameters. Intuitively, Scheffe will produce wider intervals than Bonferroni because Scheffe needs to 'include' more parameters. Are there any specific discussion of the comparison of these two methods?

Answer (score 2):

Scheffe takes into account all possible contrasts, which gives the impression that it would give the widest confidence intervals.  However, Scheffe is not dependent on the number of contrasts.  If you do 1 or 20, the CI from Scheffe will not change.  It's also more powerful than any other CI when a lot of non-pairwise contrasts are requested.

Bonferroni is dependent on how many contrasts, thus as you add more, the CI will continue to grow, in some cases becoming wider than Scheffe.

Bonferroni is one of the crudest adjustments.  Sidak is an improvement.  Both of these are only appropriate when a very small number of contrasts are planned *a priori*.  For any type of exploratory analysis, which includes anytime you add comparisons after the fact, using Scheffe is preferred.  You could possibly get away with Tukey if your exploration only includes pairwise comparisons.

Here are couple articles:

[A comparison of the Bonferroni and Scheffé bounds](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/037837589390105F?via%3Dihub)

[The Bonferroni and the Scheffé Multiple Comparison Procedures](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2297112)

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer!